# Tracking down a posted comment on my website

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, mysql, php, redhat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tracking down a posted comment](https://serverfault.com/questions/285667/tracking-down-a-posted-comment)

I have created a website on a linux redhat server which is running an apache server.  The website is coded with php and uses a mysql database.

How do I track down when a specific comment was posted to my website?

I am not using any content management system.  All web pages are created with raw php.

Comment: Dude, we just closed this question. Stop posting it.

Comment: You closed the question because it did not contain enough info, what other info do you want?  I wish people would just READ instead of closing questions inappropriately.

Comment: If your PHP code doesn't log that sort of information, then I'm afraid your out of luck.  I suggest adding that feature to your code.

Comment: @Flimzy, so basically, apache log files or mysql log files or any log file on the server cannot record what it is receiving from it's web pages?

Comment: apache only logs requests to files/php files, mysql only logs queries, to specifically log a comment posting you need to write that functionailty

Comment: Answering your question would require knowledge of implementation details on your "comment" feature. As nobody but the original developer is likely to have it, your question is not answerable in its current form.

Comment: No, those generally do not log the contents of POST methods, which is probably what you're using (if it's not, it should be) to submit those comments. Who wrote the PHP code that handles your comments? You should be asking them--they ought to know all about its inner workings, and where (if at all) it logs such things, and if not, how to make it log such things.

Comment: Your question is like asking "I built a custom car from spare parts in my garage. How do I read the check-engine status codes? The odometer doesn't tell me anything useful."

Comment: Not many experts looked at this quesiton it seems.  I was able to get all the details I needed from the log files, but it would have been nice if someone pointed me to the right log file, instead of me having to write a script to look for attempted injections.

Answer (score 1):

apache has no information about a posted comment, it just serves your files and processes your php

if you are using mysql, chances are the comment is stored in the database

if you were using wordpress the comment would be in the wp_comments table assuming a default install

if you coded the site then you should know where the comments are stored, if you dont know you should ask the person that coded it where they are stored.

take a look in the db or ask the developer is all you can do without giving us more information about the software you are running for your website

Comment: Yes, I can see the comment in the database, but I am trying to figure out which ip it was posted by, quick sql query was used to post the entry.

Comment: if the php is not written to log the IP then you wont be able to track it down, your best effort would be to match up the comment timestamp (if it has one) with the apache access log but thats like finding a needle in a haystack if your site is busy